# Try to obtain the exponent of a variable in Maple.

Tags: math-software, maple

Are there some function $f$ in Maple such that $f(K[1,2]^{1/3}) = 1/3$? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want

```
f := x -> op(2,x);
```

To be safer, you might want to use

```
f := proc(x::`^`) op(2,x) end;
```

=========

Edit: as pointed out, this doesn't work when the exponent is `1`.  Easy fix:

```
f := proc(x) `if`(x::`^` , op(2,x), 1) end;
```

Comment: thank you very much. But this doesn't work for f(K[1,2,3]). There is an error: Error, (in Indices) invalid input: exponent expects its 1st argument, x, to be of type `^`, but received K[1, 2, 3]. How could we modify your codes such that f(K[1,2,3])=1?

Answer (score 0):

Well..what about

> f:=x -> logK[1,2];

```
                  f := x -> log[K[1, 2]](x)
```

> f(K[1,2]^(1/3));

```
                             1/3
```

> 

:)

Comment: thank you very much. But this doesn't work for f(K[1, 2]^2). I obtained f(K[1,2]^2)=ln(K[1, 2]^2)/ln(K[1, 2]). How could we modify your code such that f(K[1, 2]^2)=2?